# Ip address with the address 192.168.0.0 network in http request header

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, ip, mod-perl

Using mod_perl for Apache 1.3.
Address of the client get the headers X-Forwarded-For, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FO,or environment variable $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}:

```
sub address {
    my $self = shift;
    unless(defined $self->{address}){
        my $header = $self->apache->headers_in->{'X-Forwarded-For'} ||
            $ENV{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR} || '';
        my ($ip) = $header =~ /([^,\s]+)$/;
        $self->{address} = $ip || $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} || ''; 
    }
    return $self->{address};
}
```

The problem is that sometimes there are addresses such as 192.168.200.11, 192.168.1.156, 192.168.0.73. Although the server is not connected to the network 192.168.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Expected as you are explicitly looking at [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header that (if properly set by all proxies on a way) will contain all intermediate IP and original client IP. Since most people are in local home networks most originating IPs are in 192.168.xx.xx range.